# Which words of this sentence will get stressed and a falling pitch

Tags: intonation

The sentence is:

> I finished high school in 2010.

The part I want to stress is the year, 2010.

Which words of this sentence will get stressed and a falling pitch?

How do you describe the way that "2010" sounds when it is stressed?

Comment: Depends on what you want to stress in the sentence. If you want to stress that "I" is the one who did it, or that the year is important, or high school. Or even "finished".

Comment: what about the falling pitch? I think 2010 will get a falling pitch since it's the last part of the sentence and also new information right?

Comment: If you want to stress the year, you will not have a falling pitch at all.

Comment: Then, how would you normally say the sentence?

Comment: In this example, if "in 2010" is the important piece of information, you will be stressing "2010", and most likely more particularly "10".

Comment: @MorganFR is right, there **is** no _normally_. It depends on how you _want_ to say it, which depends on the message you want to convey. Did _I_ finish high school (not you)? Did I _finish_ high school (I didn't start)? Did I finish _high school_ (not university)? Did I finish in _2010_ (not 2015)?

Comment: Yes, 2010 is the most important piece of information. Correct me if I am wrong, in other words, 10 will get a falling pitch, right?

Comment: No, in that case, the pitch will not be rising, as to make it a question, nor will it be falling at that particular part. The word "ten" will simply be stressed in comparison to the rest of the words in the sentence (strongly pronounced T sound). That is, only if "2010" is the most relevant piece of information in the sentence.

Comment: But why? Is it because it is a number? As far as I know, the last word of a new informative sentence gets a falling pitch.

Comment: The last accented syllable of a sentence usually does get a falling pitch, and I would normally pitch *ten* lower. But if I stress *ten* strongly, I don't lower the pitch. (

Comment: @Lompo1 It would help to add the relevant context to the question itself since comments are considered ephemeral at EL&U and are sometimes deleted without notice. In this instance, I've helped you to do this based on your discussion above. Feel free to roll back, or to [edit] further if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are stating it matter-of-factly, "finished" is emphasized a little, and the "10" in "2010" is emphasized more.

It also depends on your regional dialect... a southern-speaker would emphasize "I" as "EYE", and also emphasize the "high".

An Ivy-Leager or someone from Boston might emphasize "I" by saying "Ah"...

You get the point.  It's all relative so this can be emphasized in a multitude of ways.

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot! One last question, if you do not mind. look at this sentence: If she finds out about his betrayal, she will get rage. Correct me if I am wrong. 'Find' will get stressed as well as 'Betrayal' and 'Out' will get a rising pitch as well as 'Rage'. Am i right?

Comment: Well, "she will get rage" isn't correct grammar.  It should be "become enraged" and emphasis is all entirely subjective and depends on which region of the country you are from.  To me, the strongest emphasis would be on "enraged" but again... anyone could emphasize anywhere in that sentence depending on their background, education, and regional influences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so, since it is a fact, do I need to fall intonate engaged or not?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a fact - could be an opinion if someone's going to blow a gasket or not.  I'd emphasize the "rage" in "enraged".  Or... you could actually be more matter-of-fact and disconnected by stating flatly (no emphasis) on the entire clause of "she will become enraged".    I picture Morgan Freeman doing a narrative for this matter-of-fact way of stating it.  Or, if you prefer emphasis on her becoming enraged... and emphasize that portion... I picture someone gossiping or an attorney in court trying to press his point.  Make sense?